# Powerapps - Setting Variable to SharePoint User Column on Start

Tags: forms, sharepoint, powerapps

I'm creating a custom SharePoint form using PowerApps. On my SharePoint List, I have a User column called Manager.

In SharePointIntegration OnView & OnEdit I'm setting the variable ManagerEmail: Set(ManagerEmail, SharePointIntegration.Selected.Manager.Email)

(I've also tried setting the variable to the Form field: Set(ManagerEmail, DataCardValue6.Selected.Email) and this has the same issue described below)

I have a label on the form that displays ManagerEmail.

When I first view an item, the label is empty. If I view the same item again, it shows the correct information.

If I view a new item, the label shows the value from the previous item. If I view the same item again, it shows the correct information.

I've tried moving the Set command to the view OnStart and it behaves the same way. I'm clearing the variable on OnSave & OnCancel in SharePointIntegration using the command: Set(ManagerEmail, "")

Comment: Incidentally, if I set my label to SharePointIntegration.Selected.Manager.Emai directly, it works correctly every time.

Comment: So, I've found that I can put a hidden label on my screen that is set to the field value and then refer to the label text instead. Same works for referring to Office365 Profile information which has the same OnStart bug.